# Connection String test failed: Outsystems

Tags: sql, outsystems

I'm using Outsystems Service Studio to develop a web application. I need to configure a connection to access a local server database. I get "Connection String test failed:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified SQL hosts.

But I am able to connect the same database via MS SQL Server Management Studio", what is wrong?.

Please find the below image for more details about the connection issue.

[image]

Comment: The image you intended to attach isn't attached.

Comment: @STLDev, please Check now and let me know.

Comment: It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.When we copy & paste, sometimes Unicode characters will there. So need to type and fill our server details instead of copy&paste.

2.And Application Name should be full server name and then the server name should be server Ip only as like below.

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOfhy.png
```